# Induction over HIT (HoTT)

Tags: induction, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

### Setting

Currently I try to formulate the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus in HoTT which results in quite involved inductive type families. Since I'm still new, I'm often unsure if my induction principles are stated correctly.

Important is, since I'm still learning, I need an answer according to the HoTT Book, the stricter the better. Thanks a lot!

### Example

Okay, this type might not catch any greater idea, it's just a pile of syntax.
Let $A$ be any dummy type here. Then I want to consider the inductive type family $T : A \to \mathcal{U}$ given by

- $e : \Pi_{\Delta : A} T(\Delta)$
- $\_[\_] : \Pi_{\Delta : A} T(\Delta) \to \mathsf{List}(T(\Delta)) \to T(\Delta)$

as point and

- $\mathsf{re} : \Pi_{\Delta : A}\Pi_{\delta : T(\Delta)}\Pi_{l : \mathsf{List}(T(\Delta))} e[(\delta,l)] = \delta$ in $T(\Delta)$

as path constructors where $(\delta,l)$ appends $\delta$ to the list $l$.

The *induction principle* therefore: To define a function $f : \Pi_{\Delta : A} \Pi_{T(\Delta)} C(\Delta,T(\Delta))$ one needs

- $c_e : \Pi_{\Delta : A} C(\Delta, e)$
- $c_s : \Pi_{\Delta : A} \Pi_{m : T(\Delta)} \Pi_{l : \mathsf{List}(T(\Delta))} C(\Delta, m) \to C(\Delta,m[l])$

as well as a path over $\mathsf{re}$:

- $p : \Pi_{\Delta : A}\Pi_{l:\mathsf{List}(T(\Delta))}\Pi_{\delta:T(\Delta)}\Pi_{c_\delta : C(\Delta,\delta)} \;\;\;c_s(\Delta,e,(\delta,l),c_e(\Delta)) =_{\mathsf{re}}^{C(\Delta)} c_\delta$

which then yields

\begin{align*}
f(\Delta,e) &:\equiv c_e(\Delta)\\
f(\Delta,m[l]) &:\equiv c_s(\Delta,m,l,f(\Delta,m))\\
\mathsf{apd}_f(\mathsf{re}) &:= p
\end{align*}

### Questions

So, the most important question at first: Is this induction principle stated correctly, especially the dependent path?

And as a broader, more subjective question: If you use HoTT in a "working" manner, on paper then type setting it: How do you deal with big inductive definitions while working (in)formally in HoTT? Some of my definitions are made up out of 6 or more paths on 5 or so constructors, making not only the induction principle but especially proofs utilizing these quite a pain (even more so in when typing it in LaTeX).

Comment: I can't parse your definition of re.  Should it be $\delta:T(\Delta)$?  Which of the arguments of your point constructors are implicit?  And what does $e[\delta,l]$ mean?  Your second point constructor takes one argument from $T(\Delta)$, which could be either $e$ or $\delta$ but not both.

Comment: You're right, I've edited accordingly. And $e[(\delta,l)]$ is inspired by the substitution operator. And, about the implicit constructors, while writing, there arises a new question, but for now: The $\Delta$ is at least implicit.

Comment: Okay, another question: your definition as stated is parametric in $\Delta$, i.e. each constructor mentions only elements of $T(\Delta)$ for the same $\Delta$.  This means it's equivalent to a definition that takes $\Delta$ as a parameter instead of an index, i.e. each type $T(\Delta)$ is separately inductively defined and has a separate induction principle (so you can strip all the $\Pi_{\Delta:A}$s from the induction principle).  Is this what you intended?  Or did you want to give an example that is "honestly" indexed?

Comment: This is already so refreshing to have a small back-and-forth around these topics. Only reading the book is so silent from time to time (although it's written nicely). So, index vs parameter: my example is poorly in this sense, it's meant to be an "honest" index, but you're right, and I totally forgot about that. What $\Delta$ stands for is really the $\lambda$-context, which changes on some constructors (abstraction takes out a type). Although there is usually a minimal one. But I will ask about such things in a separate question...

Comment: I think your induction principle is missing something: there should be an input in $C$ that lives over the list $l$.  However, in order to phrase this one seems to need some kind of a "dependent list".  This is weird, but your inductive type is of a somewhat exotic sort in which the constructor inputs contain *other inductive types* applied to the type being defined, as opposed to the normal sort where the inputs are only elements of that type and functions with that type as codomain.  Unfortunately I don't remember offhand what this kind of inductive type is called or where it's studied.

Comment: Hm... You mean $\mathsf{List}(T(\Delta))$ is problematic, since it involves $T$ as an index, in its very definition?

Comment: If I replace $\mathsf{List}$ with some type $\mathsf{Subst}$ which is mutually inductive defined with $T$ and works like a list, does the problem disappear?

Comment: No, I don't mean there's a problem with the inductive definition itself.  I just mean that your induction principle is missing something.  Now that you mention it, I think that defining a copy of List mutually-inductively with T is the way that people usually derive induction principles for this sort of thing.